# How do I properly escape % in call to printf in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, formatting, escaping, printf, string-formatting

How do I properly escape % in call to printf in Ruby?

When I try to use `%%` (as in C),

```
value = 47
printf "To have a 60%% test average, your final exam must be at least %0.2f.\n" % [value]
```

I get this error:

```
$ ruby /tmp/test.rb 
/tmp/test.rb:4:in `printf': malformed format string - %t (ArgumentError)
    from /tmp/test.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

It appears that the `%` is being interpolated into the string before the string is checked for format arguments (i.e., the "`... %% test ...`" appears to be getting interpreted as "`... %test ...`"); however, I don't know the correct way to set up the format string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass value as an argument to printf

```
printf "To have a 60%% test average, your final exam must be at least %0.2f.\n",value
```

Comment: What's the difference between `printf "..." % [p1, p2]` and `printf " ... ", p1`. (I was taught to use the array syntax.)

Comment: In Ruby, the % operator for strings is a format operator.   You can format strings without printf by doing  `"%06d" % 100`   - I'm not sure of a reason to pass an array as the parameter to printf.   There are some advanced topics like passing an array as a list of function arguments, but just to keep it simple, pass a single value to the printf statement for each format you have in the string and that'll be easy to understand for everyone.

Comment: @Zack - looks like your array syntax is for passing multiple arguments to the `%` operator - you don't even need `printf` if you're using `%`

Comment: Right on that last comment. Both `String#%` and `Kernel#printf` interpret the `%`s in the string. `printf s % args` calls `String#%` then feeds that method's result to `printf` as a format string so you're effectively saying `puts sprintf(sprintf(s, args))` and that's a bit strange.

Comment: Now I see.  I didn't realize that the `%` was a String method:  I thought it was just a quirky part of the `printf` syntax.